# Blocking latex from using an entire page to place figures

Tags: graphics

Within my article, I have just added 3 images one after the other. I guess the three images together would take more or less 70% of the page. However, Latex has choose to use the whole page to display these images, resulting into a very unpleasant layout. I would like to prevent in this case Latex from using the entire page solely for these images.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `p` (float page) possibility using the optional argument

```
\begin{figure}[t]
```

LaTeX will never create a float page for such a figure but will hold it until it can be positioned on a page with text, unless `\clearpage` (or implicit `\clearpage` such as `\end{document}`) forces all pending floats to be typeset.

Comment: Thank you @David. That has worked indeed, but I got the third image to be placed in the following page. Any way I can retrieve it, and be positioned together with the other two?

Comment: @LucaDanieli you can put all three images and all three captions in a single `figure` then they will float together or perhaps your document class doesn't allow more than two floats er page you could increase `topnum` or use `[!t]` to ignore that constraint.